# How to sum two fields inside a bool Query in Elastic Search?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch to find my result. How I sum two fields inside my query?

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "term": { "x.flag1": "false" } },
        { "term": { "x.flag2": "false" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to  find sum of two fields `x.a` and `x.b` and compare it with an other field, say `x.c`

```
(x.a + x.b === x.c)
```

I have to include this inside the bool query. So that only those records that satisfy both these conditions will be in my result. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via a [`script` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) like this:

The query for ES 2.x onwards:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "x.flag1": "false"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "x.flag2": "false"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc['x.a'].value + doc['x.b'].value === doc['x.c'].value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The same query for a pre-2.0 ES version:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "x.flag1": "false"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "x.flag2": "false"
              }
            },
            {
              "script": {
                "script": "doc['x.a'].value + doc['x.b'].value === doc['x.c'].value"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) for this to work (i.e. `script.inline: true`).

However, if you have many documents, this can quickly slow down your ES cluster. If possible this should be done at indexing time, where you'd create another boolean field exactly for this purpose and then you can simply filter documents based on that boolean field which contains the `true/false` condition you need.

Comment: : QueryParsingException[[dooht] [bool] query does not support [filter]]; i got this error what to do?

Comment: Are you on a pre-2.0 ES version by any chance?

Comment: Oh .. i have 1.74 ES

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100147/discussion-between-mariya-james-and-val).